# Connections and Projection Maps

Tags: connections

Let $M$ be a manifold and let $\pi: TM\rightarrow M$ be the projection map.  Taking the pushforward of $\pi$ we obtain a bundle map
$$
\pi_\ast: T(TM)\rightarrow TM.
$$
Let
$$
V=\ker \pi_\ast
$$
be the vertical subbundle of $T(TM)$.

Let $\nabla$ be a covariant derivative on $M$.  How does $\nabla$ define a **smooth** bundle map $K: T(TM)\rightarrow T(TM)$ such that $K(T(TM))=V$ and $K^2=K$? Also, is it true that there is a one to one correspondence between covariant derivatives on $M$ and smooth bundle maps $K:T(TM)\rightarrow T(TM)$ satisfying $K^2=K$ and $K(T(TM))=V$?

Of course, the bundle map $K$ with the above properties defines a decomposition
$$
T(TM)=H\oplus V
$$
where $H:=\ker K$ is the so-called horizontal distribution.

I have seen similar questions on Stack Exchange but the constructions given in the comments or answers either do not seem well defined or they do not appear to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $M$ be a manifold and $\nabla$ a connection on $M$.  Let $D/dt$ denote the induced covariant derivative for vector fields on $M$ defined along curves.  Let $\sigma: (a,b)\rightarrow M$ be a (smooth) curve and let $X:(a,b)\rightarrow TM$ be a vector field along $c$.  In other words, if $\pi: TM\rightarrow M$ is the projection, then
$$
c(t)=\pi(X(t))
$$
or $X(t)\in T_{c(t)}M$. Let $t_0\in (a,b)$ and choose a coordinate neihborhood $(U,x_i)$ of $p=c(t_0)$.  Let $\varepsilon>0$ be such that $(t_0-\varepsilon, t_0+\varepsilon)\subset (a,b)$ and
$$
c(t_0-\varepsilon, t_0+\varepsilon)\subset U.
$$
Write $c(t)$ and $X(t)$ for $t\in (t_0-\varepsilon, t_0+\varepsilon)$ in local coordinates:
$$
c(t)=(c^i(t)),\hspace{0.1in} X(t)=X^i(t)\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\big|_{c(t)}
$$
where Einstein notation is employed in the expression for $X(t)$. The covariant derivative of $X(t)$ is then
$$
\frac{DX}{dt}(t)=\left(\frac{dX^k}{dt}+\frac{dc^i}{dt}X^j\Gamma^k_{ij}\right)\frac{\partial}{\partial x^k}\big|_{c(t)}\in T_{c(t)}M
$$
where $\Gamma^k_{ij}$ are the Chrisoffel symbols of $\nabla$.

The idea now is to use $D/dt$ to define a map $K: T(TM)\rightarrow T(TM)$ with the desired properties.

For convenience, we will denote the tangent vector $v\in T_p M$ as $(p,v)$.  Note that
$$
V_{(p,v)} = T_{(p,v)}(T_pM) \simeq T_p M
$$
and the isomorphism between $V_{(p,v)}$ and $T_pM$ is canonical because $T_pM$ is a vector space.  Specifically, given a tangent vector $Y\in T_pM$, we associate it to the vector which in $Y_v\in V_{(p,v)}$ which is specified by the curve
$$
\alpha(t)=(p,v+tY)\in T_pM\subset TM.
$$
In other words,
$$
\alpha(0)=(p,v),\hspace{0.1in} \dot{\alpha}(0)=Y_v\in V_{(p,v)}.
$$
We can express $Y_v$ in terms of local coordinates as follows.  Writing
$$
Y=Y^i\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\big|_p,
$$
let $(TU,x^i,y^i)$ be the coordinate system induced by $(U,x^i)$.  Then one sees that
$$
Y_v = Y^i\frac{\partial}{\partial y^i}\big|_{(p,v)}
$$
The map $K: TTM\rightarrow TTM$ is then defined as follows.  For $\xi\in T_{(p,v)}TM$, let $X:(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)$ be any curve such that
$$
X(0)=(p,v),\hspace{0.1in}\dot{X}(0)=\xi.
$$
We then define
$$
K\xi = \left(\frac{DX}{dt}(0)\right)_v\in V_{(p,v)}.
$$
This definition is independent of the choice of curve $X(t)$.  This is clear by expressing $K\xi$ in local coordinates.  Write
$$
\xi = \xi^i_{(1)} \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\big|_{(p,v)}+\xi^i_{(2)} \frac{\partial}{\partial y^i}\big|_{(p,v)}
$$
Let $c_X(t)=\pi(X(t))$ and write
$$
X(t) = X^i(t)\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\big|_{c(t)},\hspace{0.2in} v=v^i\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\big|_{p}
$$
Since $X(0)=(p,v)$ and $\dot{X}(0)=\xi$, we have
$$
X^i(0)=v^i,\hspace{0.1in} \frac{dc_X^i}{dt}(0)=\xi^i_{(1)}, \hspace{0.1in}\frac{dX^i}{dt}(0)=\xi^i_{(2)}
$$
So
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{DX}{dt}(0)&=\left(\frac{dX^k}{dt}(0)+\frac{dc^i}{dt}(0)X^j(0)\Gamma^k_{ij}(p)\right)\frac{\partial}{\partial x^k}\big|_{p}\\
&=\left(\xi^k_{(2)}+\xi^i_{(1)}v^j\Gamma^k_{ij}(p)\right)\frac{\partial}{\partial x^k}\big|_{p}
\end{align}
$$
$K\xi$ is then
$$
K\xi=\left(\frac{DX}{dt}(0)\right)_v=\left(\xi^k_{(2)}+\xi^i_{(1)}v^j\Gamma^k_{ij}(p)\right)\frac{\partial}{\partial y^k}\big|_{(p,v)}
$$
The definition of $K\xi$ in local coordinates makes it clear that $K$ is linear on the fibers of $TTM$ and that its smooth.  Also, note that if $\xi\in V_{(p,v)}$, then the components $\xi^i_{(1)}=0$ and
$$
K\xi=\xi^k_{(2)}\frac{\partial}{\partial y^k}\big|_{(p,v)}=\xi.
$$
By construction, the image of $K$ is all of $V$.  Also, since $K$ is the identity on $V$, we also have $K^2=K$.  $K$ is then the desired smooth bundle map.